# Difference in Exposed API signature from the DLL

Tags: c++, c

I am building a C/C++ project and I have added 3 API which I intended to expose. When I built them, I was able to see them from **DLL Export Viewer** as expected. For reference see below:
[image]

I then moved the content to a file so as to logically group them together and have tried building the dll again. Now, if I check I see slight differences. For reference, see below:
[image]

As you can see, the first version had just `AA_component_XXX` API exposed and in the second version I see `int _cdecl AA_component_XXX`. These APIs would be called by the core framework and that is having problems invoking the second version of the API.

I am building using Visual Studio. Please let me know where/what to look for to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is "C/C++"?

Comment: It is a C++ dll that has C and C++ intermixed.

Comment: You have - changed / not defined / missed a #define - for the calling conventions of the moved functions.